# read in Bash and ZSH

Tags: bash, script, zsh, read

I'm observing differences between zsh and bash when using read on macOS.

With bash this script

```
echo "characters" | while IFS= read -d '' -n 1 a; do printf %s "$a-"; done
```

Produces

```
c-h-a-r-a-c-t-e-r-s-
```

Whereas on zsh I have no output and no errors
Is it possible to use read to iterate character by character?

Answer (score 10):

The options for the `read` command are significantly different between bash and zsh. In this case, the problem is that `-n` has completely different meanings between the two: in bash, it says how many characters to read, while in zsh it modifies the `-p` or `-l` options (which have to do with completion functions, and are irrelevant here).

In zsh, you use `-k` to specify the number of characters to read, but it also defaults to reading from the terminal rather than stdin, so you have to also add `-u 0` to tell it to read from stdin.

Long story short: in zsh, use `read -n '' -k 1 -u 0 somevar` to read a single character from stdin.

BTW, there are lots more differences between `read` in bash vs zsh (and vs other shells). The [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html#tag_20_109) only specifies the `-r` option; everything else is a nonstandard addition, and any similarity between different shells' extensions should be considered a happy accident.

Comment: Additionally in general Zsh does not try to be POSIX-compliant in the first place. For me this means its support for `read -r` is also an accident or a deliberate courtesy.

Comment: `zsh` isn't POSIX-compliant *by default*. It's possible to make it POSIX-compatible by invoking it, e.g, as `sh`. (Though to be honest, I've never tested how well the compatibility works.)

Comment: @chepner True, but zsh tends to follow POSIX *unless there's a reason to violate it*. For example, word splitting causes more problems than it solves, so zsh disables it by default. Though it occurs to me that, by that reasoning, you almost always want `-r`, so it'd be reasonable to make that the default (and then add a nonstandard option to turn backslash interpretation back).